# FilePathResult serves file from Temp folder not the path provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using PDFSharp, I have created and successfully saved a pdf file in a specific folder. Then I want to serve this file to the user on the browser upon request.

```
  return filePathResult = File(pdfFilePath,
                    MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(pdfFilePath),
                    string.Format("{0}-data.pdf", userProfile.FullName));
```

The user gets open or save file prompt on the browser, but opening the file brings a pdf file that is created on the fly in the `/AppData/Local/Temp/data.pdf`, which has no content. I have done a lot of work around it, but so far I have not been able to force FilePathResult to serve the PDF file that I have created instead of creating a file in the temp folder and serving it to the user. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you understand what is happening or why (or how file serving to browsers works). What happens when the save file prompt is chosen in the browser? What is `FilePathResult`?

Comment: @NetMage when I choose save file prompt, a pdf file with the same name (-data.pdf) is saved in the Download folder. This pdf file contains nothing. It is a blank file. However, the PDF file that is generated by PDFSharp and is supposed to be served contains a lot of data and it is supposed to be served from a path that I have defined, not from the Temp folder.

Comment: The file is not being served from the `Temp` folder, it is being downloaded by the browser to the `Temp` folder - unless the URL in the PDF viewer is `http:/../AppData/Local/Temp/data.pdf` in which case you have huge server security issues.

Comment: @NetMage Well, the URL in the PDF viewer is file:///C:/Users/P/AppData/Local/Temp/-data.pdf, so perhaps I don't have security issue. So, this is another mystery to me now that why the file that is copied to the Temp folder is different than the file that is generated and saved by PDFSharp?

Comment: You need to show more code to debug/analyze that. How are you serving the file to the browser? Have you verified the file created on the server is correct and not empty?